# How to remove a '^[[2K' sequence from cli output?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

A query engine outputs text that contains this sequence that looks like '^[[2K' on my terminal. I could not find anything in google about it and I am wondering how to remove it from the output.

```
CPU Time: 3.8s total, 26.3M rows/s,  143MB/s, 18% active
^[[2KPer Node: 0.5 parallelism, 14.4M rows/s, 78.6MB/s
Parallelism: 2.7
^[[2KPeak Memory: 24B
0:01 [100M rows, 544MB] [72.2M rows/s, 393MB/s]
```

I have tried tr but did not work properly:

```
 tr -d '^[[2K'
```

Is there a better approach for this?

Comment: It is an [ANSI escape sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_sequences) used to clear the line of the terminal. It is used to update the content of the current line. It seems your terminal does not interpret it correctly.

Comment: [how to delete characters from stream linux bash](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+delete+characters+from+stream+linux+bash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ echo -e 'CPU Time: 3.8s total, 26.3M rows/s,  143MB/s, 18% active
\033[2KPer Node: 0.5 parallelism, 14.4M rows/s, 78.6MB/s
Parallelism: 2.7
\033[2KPeak Memory: 24B
0:01 [100M rows, 544MB] [72.2M rows/s, 393MB/s]' | sed 's/'"$(echo -e "\033")"'\[2K//'
```

outputs:

```
CPU Time: 3.8s total, 26.3M rows/s,  143MB/s, 18% active
Per Node: 0.5 parallelism, 14.4M rows/s, 78.6MB/s
Parallelism: 2.7
Peak Memory: 24B
0:01 [100M rows, 544MB] [72.2M rows/s, 393MB/s]
```

`^[` is the way the terminal displays the `\033` octal or `0x1b` value. It's the char that begins ascii escpae sequence. `tr` is a tool for deleting characters (not strings, single characters), so it won't work for that. Here I used `sed` that should replace the string  with nothing: `sed 's/'"$(echo -e "\033")"'\[2K//'`